# How to return to branch with files I forgot to commit?

Tags: git

I was on branch `A` and modified some files. I forgot to commit them. Then I switched to branch `B` and suddenly remembered about files. Now, when I am trying to switch back to branch `A` it disallows me, saying

```
The following working tree files would be overwritten by checkout
```

And giving the list of my modified files.

How to switch and keep files as on disk? I guess if I do `--force` it will overwrite files with branch versions with is not applicable.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452 - I usually recommend avoiding `git stash` but this is one thing it actually is pretty good for. :-)

Comment: "I was on branch A and modified some files"  and  "Then I switched to branch B" without committing the changes. Wasn't `git` suppose to abort this checkout?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `git stash`, then `git checkout A` and then `git stash apply`

Comment: I believe you want `git stash apply`, not `git apply`. :)

Comment: Lol. Typo. Just noticed it. Thanks.